# How to create a CFDictionary in an OS X target?

Tags: swift, macos, core-foundation, cfstring, cfdictionary

According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDictionaryRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/CFDictionaryCreate) `CFDictionaryCreate` is used to instantiate CFDictionary in `swift`.

```
func CFDictionaryCreate(_ allocator: CFAllocator!,
                  _ keys: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Void>>,
                  _ values: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Void>>,
                  _ numValues: CFIndex,
                  _ keyCallBacks: UnsafePointer<CFDictionaryKeyCallBacks>,
                  _ valueCallBacks: UnsafePointer<CFDictionaryValueCallBacks>) -> CFDictionary!
```

How can I create the `keys` and `values` arguments? 
So far I've tried to use swift's `String` type hoping it would be automatically converted to appropriate types:

```
import Foundation

var keys : [String] = ["key1", "key2"]
var values : [String] = ["value1", "value2"]
var keyCallbacks = kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks
var valueCallbacks = kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks
var dict : CFDictionary = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
    &keys, &values, 2, &keyCallbacks, &valueCallbacks)
```

Unfortunately I receive an error saying `String` is not the right type for `keys` and `values` array elements:

```
main.swift:41:2: error: 'String' is not identical to 'UnsafePointer<Void>'
    &configKeys, &configValues, 3, &keyCallbacks, &valueCallbacks)
```

How do I make an `UnsafePointer<Void>` from `String`?

Comment: The easiest way is `let dict:CFDictionary = ["key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"]` :)

Answer (score 8):

For Swift 3 you need extra casting to `CFDictionary`.
Otherwise *Contextual type 'CFDictionary' cannot be used with dictionary* literal is thrown.

```
let options: CFDictionary = [kSecImportExportPassphrase as String : "certificateKey"] as CFDictionary
```

See https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2388 for more.

Answer (score 3):

rintaro's comment worked for String literals, but not when I was working with a `CFStringRef` and a Swift `String`:

```
// Error: Contextual type 'CFDictionary' cannot be used with dictionary literal
let options: CFDictionary = [kSecImportExportPassphrase : "certificateKey"]
```

I had to cast the CFStringRef as a Swift String:

```
let options: CFDictionary = [kSecImportExportPassphrase as String : "certificateKey"] // works
```