# How to convert array to UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeRawPointer?> Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, unsafe-pointers, unsafemutablepointer

Here was my workable code in the previous version of Swift:

```
 let imageOptionsDictKeys = [ kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, kCVPixelBufferWidthKey,  kCVPixelBufferHeightKey, kCVPixelBufferOpenGLESCompatibilityKey, kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey]
 let imageOptionsDictValues = [ cvPixelFormatType,  frameW, frameH, boolYES]

 var keyCallbacks = kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks
 var valueCallbacks = kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks

 let imageOptions = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafeMutablePointer(imageOptionsDictKeys), UnsafeMutablePointer(imageOptionsDictValues), 4, &keyCallbacks, &valueCallbacks)
```

After changes in the Swift 3.0 I have to convert my keys and values arrays into `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeRawPointer?>` for creating CFDictionary.

This way:

```
    let imageOptionsDictKeysPointer =  UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeRawPointer?>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    imageOptionsDictKeysPointer.initialize(to: imageOptionsDictKeys)
```

gives an Bad Access error.

And after reading documentation I am trying to compile this code:

```
        let imageOptionsDictKeys = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, kCVPixelBufferWidthKey,  kCVPixelBufferHeightKey, kCVPixelBufferOpenGLESCompatibilityKey]
        let imageOptionsDictKeysRawPointer = Unmanaged.passUnretained(imageOptionsDictKeys).toOpaque()
        let imageOptionsDictKeysPointer =  UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeRawPointer?>.allocate(capacity: 1)
        imageOptionsDictKeysPointer.initialize(to: imageOptionsDictKeysRawPointer)

        let imageOptionsDictValues = [ cvPixelFormatType,  frameW, frameH, boolYES]
        let imageOptionsDictValuesRawPointer = Unmanaged.passUnretained(imageOptionsDictValues).toOpaque()
        let imageOptionsDictValuesPointer =  UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeRawPointer?>.allocate(capacity: 1)
        imageOptionsDictValuesPointer.initialize(to: imageOptionsDictValuesRawPointer)

        let imageOptions = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, imageOptionsDictKeysPointer, imageOptionsDictValuesPointer, 4, &keyCallbacks, &valueCallbacks)
```

but error  **Generic parameter 'Instance' could not be inferred** appears in the lines **Unmanaged.passUnretained(*array*).toOpaque()**

I have no idea how to create CFDictionary programmatically now.

Comment: Don't create a CFDictionary. Create a Swift Dictionary instead, as for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38171414/1187415.

Comment: I have to call function VTCompressionSessionCreate(....) with CFDictionary params. I am not sure that I can to use just Swift Dictionary... or are they convertible somehow?

Comment: Seems like an unnecessarily complicated way of making a `CFDictionary`, and a textbook [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). See http://stackoverflow.com/q/29301302/3141234

Comment: For now I`ve just simplify the creation of CFDictionary. It looks like dictionary are created, but my next step still not working. Maybe it is because of this dictionary, I am not sure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39987373/videotoolbox-does-not-create-an-encoder-session-for-mpeg4-in-swift-3-0

Answer (score -1):

I just solved a similar issue converting arrays to `UnsafeMutablePointer< UnsafeMutablePointer<T>>` which you can find here:
[Swift 3 UnsafeMutablePointer initialization for C type float**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40128275/swift-3-unsafemutablepointer-initialization-for-c-type-float/40135482#40135482)

To convert swift arrays using the same scheme, use `UnsafeMuTablePointer` as suggested here: http://technology.meronapps.com/2016/09/27/swift-3-0-unsafe-world-2/