# Swift 3 UnsafeMutablePointer initialization for C type float**

Tags: c, swift3, unsafemutablepointer

Within Swift 3, I need to send data to a C object accepting `float **` input.

In Swift 2, I used to declare a `UnsafeMutablePointer< UnsafeMutablePointer<Float32>>`, construct a swift Array (only for init!), and pass this to the pointer, and it worked:

```
    var bufferOut: UnsafeMutablePointer< UnsafeMutablePointer<Float32>>?
    arrayOut = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: Int(size1), count: Int(size2))
    bufferOut = UnsafeMutablePointer< UnsafeMutablePointer<Float32>>(arrayOut)
```

This is all broken now in Swift 3!

- What is the most Swifty way to pass a C-Style `float**` and initialize it?
- What would be the best way to assign values in a `UnsafeMutablePointer< UnsafeMutablePointer<T>>`?

Documentations say that for `T **` one should use `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<T>` but I actually never managed to construct one!

Note that I don't actually care for the Array in the above example! If I could just initialize the Pointer directly using known capacities, I would.

**Note**: The [Expected use cases Section of UnsafeRawPointer](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0107-unsaferawpointer.md#expected-use-cases) describes useful situations such C array and C Buffers, however translating such methods for the above construct is not evident!

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I ended up doing and is working. It follows recommendations from [new UnsafeMuTablePointer Reference](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0107-unsaferawpointer.md) showing example programs on simple schemes. In summary, it is required to allocate *and* assign each slot starting from top-level!

So in order to construct an `UnsafeMutablePointer< UnsafeMutablePointer<T>>` of size (size1, size2) (like a matrix), you can go ahead as follows using an intermediate vector here called `vectorBuf`:

```
    var vectorBuf : UnsafeMutablePointer<T>?
    vectorBuf = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.allocate(capacity: size2)
    for index in 0...(size2) {     // had Int(channelCount)*
        vectorBuf!.advanced(by: index).pointee = 0.0
    }

    /// This is where allocation and initialization happens:
    bufferOut = UnsafeMutablePointer< UnsafeMutablePointer<T>?>.allocate(capacity: Int(size1))
    for index in 0...Int(size1) {
        bufferOut!.advanced(by: index).pointee = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.allocate(capacity: (size2) )
        bufferOut!.advanced(by: index).pointee?.assign(from: vectorBuf!, count: size2)
    }
```

Hope this can be useful to others trying to use swift with signal processing calls in C/C++!